# How to: Mesa on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mesa, 19.04

I am on ubuntu 19.04 codename disco dingo.

When I type this :

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

I get this

```
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56
```

same with binary driver :

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.107
```

I hope I'm understanding correctly but I though mesa would come with ubuntu 19.04?

I also did the following :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

this did not help

How am I supposed to get mesa on ubuntu 19.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Nvidia 418.56 proprietary driver. Wikipedia states:

> Proprietary graphics drivers (e.g. Nvidia GeForce driver and Catalyst) replace all of Mesa, providing their own implementation of a graphics API.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)

In other words, Mesa would be disabled by this driver.

Comment: @tatsu, try reading this answer again and the link provided. If you want to use mesa then remove the Nvidia drivers. This may provide a worse experience depending on your hardware (which isn't included in your question

Comment: with "Nouveau" I get : `OpenGL version string: 4.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.2`. So the solution was installing the (previously stock) Nouveau driver as opposed to the (now stock) 418+