# Error in plot rendering with gpu_shader4 extension in Ubuntu 18.04 WSL and X server

Tags: nvidia, xorg, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mesa

I'm working with WSL1 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) in a 64bits Windows 10 Pro version 20H2 and I'm using Xming to export the graphical applications that I use on daily tasks. I have a **NVIDIA MX150** graphics card (default Dell notebook GPU), and the NVidia **driver version is 451.67**. Currently, I've been struggling with plotting results from a time-dependent numerical simulation in a python environment. I still don't know why sometimes the plot works fine and other times it doesn't work at all. I'm using the *FEniCs* framework (https://fenicsproject.org/) to generate my results and the *vedo* package (https://pypi.org/project/vedo/) to post-process the results. I realized that vedo uses **MESA** instead of **Nvidia** graphic driver.

```
$ uname --all
Linux NoteDell 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To make the graphical connection I added the following lines at the end of *bashrc* file

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/runtime-heitorvc
export RUNLEVEL=3
```

When I run my python script I get the following error:

```
ERROR: In /work/standalone-x64-build/VTK-source/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 797
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x28ba190): GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I came across this thread from another user in a similar situation as mine:
https://discourse.slicer.org/t/conflict-vmtk-with-opengl-mesa-in-nvidia-graphics-card/8765

I tried following his advances but I still experience the error mentioned above. I believe that it is due to a conflict between NVidia Graphic Driver and MESA (as mentioned here: [How to: Mesa on ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135653/how-to-mesa-on-ubuntu-19-04)).

I don't know what else to do. I thought I'd solve the problem by disabling the Nvidia graphics driver but the error persists. I'm persisting in using Vedo in my post-processing tasks due to the lack of tools to check time-dependent results efficiently (using paraview is not an option when you need to constantly test several changes in your application). Also, I believe my struggle is also affected by my lack of confidence in changing stuff in WSL, I've had some complications doing that in the past.

Can anyone share some thoughts on how to address this conflict between MESA and Nvidia under the WSL scope? How could I approach this problem? I apologize if this is not the best place to post this question.

Comment: This is likely a limitation of xming I think - see for example [xming 7.7.0.23 OpenGl version reported incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075339/xming-7-7-0-23-opengl-version-reported-incorrectly)